# OpenCart upgraded to 3.0.3.2, and I get an error in the account register section

Tags: opencart, upgrade, vqmod

I have updated OpenCart to version 3.0.3.2.

In the account register section, I'm getting an error like this:

> Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getGeneralSetting in
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/beta/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_action.php
>   on line 81

Could anyone help me with this?

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: There's no way to answer this since `getGeneralSetting` is called from somewhere in some 3rd party controller that we can't see and isn't part of Opencart core

Answer (score 0):

"vqcache/vq2-system_engine_action" this tells me it's related to vQmod, try uninstalling all vQmods (rename them from *.xml to *.xml_).

If that doesn't fix it, uninstall vQmod itself.

Comment: vqmod uninstalled but still error exists Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getGeneralSetting in /home/xxx/public_html/beta/system/engine/action.php on line 79

Comment: normal method .. website url/install/ and upgraded to latest version

Comment: "normal method" *facepalm* There are lots of methods, this does not help.